Expensify get employee data in expense report via API
I am trying to fetch expenses from expensify using API.
Here is the code I am using.
api_url = "https://integrations.expensify.com/Integration-Server/ExpensifyIntegrations"

params = {

            "requestJobDescription": dumps({
                "type": "file",
                "credentials": {
                    "partnerUserID": userid,
                    "partnerUserSecret": ssecret
                },
                "onReceive": {
                    "immediateResponse": ["returnRandomFileName"]
                },
                "inputSettings": {
                    "type": "combinedReportData",
                    "reportState": "APPROVED",
                    "limit": 80,
                    "filters": {
                        "startDate": start_date
                    }
                },
                "outputSettings": {
                    "fileExtension": "txt",
                    "fileBasename": "output_"
                }
            }),
            "template": file_template
        }

I am not able to fetch data of employee(who posted/created this expense).
I have used following fields in case it contains data required:
"owner"
"card_name"
"submitter_id"
"submitter_email"
"manager_email"

I am only getting manager_email, for other columns I am getting blank output(no data).
Is there a way to get employee/user who created expense data?
